# Why does the variance of a Brownian motion increase linearly with time?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, variance, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Brownian motion is said to follow a path where each value is normally distributed with mean $\mu t$ and variance $\sigma^2 t$.

What is the basis for the relation that variance varies directly proportional to the 1st power of $t$?

Comment: It follows directly from the definition of the process (specifically, the variance of the increments and the fact that they are independent). Are you asking for a formal proof of this fact? Or an intuitive explanation or illustration?

Comment: Hi: Hamilton's Time Series Analysis has a decent discussion of this question without the use of  stochastic differential equation type math. What you want to look at depends heavily on your math background and also as chris haug said, on what you want.

Comment: @ChrisHaug How about both? I don't have any info on the proof or the intuition.

Comment: @mlofton I graduated in engineering. But i work in finance. I was trying to study Black Scholes equation from scratch.

Comment: Could you share with us the definition of Brownian Motion you are working with?  For many of us, the question you ask is a key part of the definition.  Evidently, then, you have a different definition in mind, so we need to know what it might be.

Comment: @whuber So you are saying that only those motions whose variance are linearly related with time can be considered Brownian? Because I thought brownian motion had only to do with randomness.

Comment: In that case you are asking about a decidedly different concept than the standard Brownian Motion.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process, study characteristic (3), and please clarify your post.

Comment: @whuber In that wiki page -> Characterisations of the Wiener process -> point number 3. How did it come to be?

Comment: In a random walk, independent random "impulses" are imparted to a particle at regular intervals.  Since the variance of a sum of independent variables is the sum of their variances, the variance at the end must be directly proportional to the time elapsed.  Thus, this linear relationship becomes a basic requirement of any probability model of a such a phenomenon.

Comment: Hi: If you want to study black-scholes from scratch, do you mean want to understand the derivation of the black scholes equation  or do you want to understand stochastic differential equations. They are not the same thing because Black Scholes USES stochastic differential equations and  Ito's Lemma but one doesn't need to understand those concepts  that well in order to be able to understand the black-scholes derivation. So, it's best to be very specific. There is tons of literature but the trip  varies depending on your objective.